# Как вызвать конструктор из другого класс?

Tags: java

```
public class MyInitTest {
  private String a;
  private double c;
  private int n;

  {
    a = "non-static initialization block ";
    System.out.println(a);
  }

  {
    c = 20.03652;
    System.out.println(c + a);
  }

  static private String string;
  static private int anInt;

  static {
    string = "Static block";
    System.out.println(string);
  }

  static {
    anInt = 6;
    System.out.println(anInt + "Static block");
  }

  public MyInitTest() {
    System.out.println("Constructor1");

  }

  public MyInitTest(int i) {
    System.out.println("Constructor2");

  }
}


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInitTest myInitTest = new MyInitTest();
  }
}
```

Comment: из которого нужно вызывать? обичным способом вызываете, когда делаете `new`

Answer (score 1):

Под этим вопросом уже представлены основные варианты вызова конструктора но я добавлю еще один - рефлексией;

```
package pack;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class StartPoint {

    public StartPoint() {
        System.out.println("-");
    }

    public StartPoint(String g) {
        System.out.println("g");
    }

    private StartPoint(int i) {
        System.out.println("i");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class someClassAsExampleStartPointClass = Class.forName("pack.StartPoint");
        Constructor[] a = someClassAsExampleStartPointClass.getConstructors();
        for (Constructor temp : a) {
            System.out.println(temp); 
            // public pack.StartPoint(java.lang.String) and public pack.StartPoint() ;)
        }
        a = someClassAsExampleStartPointClass.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor temp : a) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            // **private pack.StartPoint(int)** ,public pack.StartPoint(java.lang.String) and public pack.StartPoint() ;)
        }
        System.out.println(a[0].newInstance(new Integer(12))); // out ->> "i"  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если

```
MyInitTest myInitTest = new MyInitTest();
```

вызывается конструктор

```
public MyInitTest() {
  System.out.println("Constructor1");
}
```

---

Если

```
MyInitTest myInitTest = new MyInitTest(1000);
```

вызывается конструктор

```
public MyInitTest(int i) {
  System.out.println("Constructor2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//указывать пакет, где находится исходный класс, важно!
package model;

//Если классы не связаны:
public class MyInitTest2 {
    String a;
    Integer b;
// объявление экземпляра класса, конструктор еще не вызывается.    
    MyInitTest aaa;

    public MyInitTest2()
   {
       a = "Test2";
       b = 10;
// Инициализация, а вот тут как раз происходит вызов конструктора.
       aaa = new MyInitTest();
   }
}
```

Второй вариант вызова:

```
package model;

    // Если класс является наследником
    public class MyInitTest3 extends MyInitTest{
        String a;
        Integer b;    

        public MyInitTest3()
       {   
           // первым у наследуемых классов всегда вызывается конструктор родителя
           // для этого используется ключевое слово super
           super();
           a = "Test2";
           b = 10;
       }  
    }
```